# Hosting webapp with relative URLs behind Kubernetes NGINX ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am hosting a web application inside a Kubernetes 1.13 cluster behind an NGINX [ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx). The `Ingress` specifies `path: /my-webapp/?(.*)` and `annotations:
{ nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1 }` such that the webapp can be reached from outside the cluster at `http://my-cluster/my-webapp`. (The ingress controller is exposed as `my-cluster`.)

One remaining problem is that the webapp contains "relative" URLs that refer e.g. to CGI scripts and to CSS stylesheets. For instance, the stylesheet in `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/my-stylesheet.css" />` currently does not load. I assume this is because the browser requests it at the wrong URL (`http://my-cluster/my-webapp/my-stylesheet.css` would be right) and that some more annotations are needed.

What is the correct configuration is such a case?

**UPDATE** The inspector reveals that the browser currently requests the stylesheet from URL `http://my-cluster/my-stylesheet.css`, which is indeed wrong and needs to be fixed.

**UPDATE** [This](https://serverfault.com/questions/561892/how-to-handle-relative-urls-correctly-with-a-reverse-proxy) looks like a related problem with an NGINX reverse proxy in general, not a Kubernetes NGINX ingress controller in particular. I wonder if and how the suggested recipes can also serve in this particular case. For a start, I have tried switching to a relative URL for referencing the stylesheet (per recipe One in the accepted answer), but this also has not worked so far: 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my-stylesheet.css" />`, the browser apparently still tries to get the stylesheet from `http://my-cluster/my-stylesheet.css`, although it displays `http://my-cluster/my-webapp` in the URL bar and the inspector reports the same URL as `baseURI`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Now [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/pull/3174) combination of annotations seems to do the trick:

```
annotations:
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    sub_filter '<head>' '<head> <base href="/my-webapp/">';
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
```

I am currently using this [version](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#detect-installed-version) of the ingress controller:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NGINX Ingress controller
  Release:    0.23.0
  Build:      git-be1329b22
  Repository: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: but doesn't that do it for any other path?  if you added /myapi it would fail

Comment: To solve the issue mentioned by Brett, you can replace the hard-coded <base href="/my-webapp/"> by a variable that matches the path:  <base href="/$1/">.

To make regex assign the path to $1, put it between parenthesis, as follows:
<pre>
      - host: demo.localdev.me
        http:
          paths:
          - path: /(my-webapp)/?(.*)
    ...
          - path: /(my-other-webapp)/?(.*)
    ...
</pre>
Now $2 matches the remainer of the path, so:

nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, I must replace URL-s from wsdl service page and this my solution code that was written thanks to the above code

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
  sub_filter 'http://example.com:80/project/domain/' 'http://example.com:80${PUBLISH_PATH}/project/domain/';
  sub_filter_once off;
  sub_filter_types text/xml;
```

${PUBLISH_PATH} - is the kuber domain specific